# SOLR 4.10.3 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: position increments (and gaps) must be >= 0 (got 65536) for field

Tags: solr

we've added AutoPhraseTokenFilter on our SOLR 4.10.3 installation used in a Drupal 7 website and everything works fine but SOLR throws an error when it tries to index a big Excel 2010 file (1MB, around 5000 lines spread across 5 tabs). Here's the trace:

> SearchApiException while indexing: "500" Status: Server Error: Server
>   Error{"responseHeader":{"status":500,"QTime":193},"error":{"msg":"Exception
>   writing document id 81pf49-index_par_d_faut_des_n_uds-6294 to the
>   index; possible analysis
>   error.","trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception
>   writing document id 81pf49-index_par_d_faut_des_n_uds-6294 to the
>   index; possible analysis error.\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:168)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:926)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1080)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)\r\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nCaused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: position increments (and gaps)
>   must be >= 0 (got 65536) for field
>   'tm_attachments_field_fichier'\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:633)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:359)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:318)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:239)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:457)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1511)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:240)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)\r\n\t...
>   40 more\r\n","code":500}} in SearchApiSolrConnection->checkResponse()
>   (line 541 of C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\atrium\sites\all\modules\search_api_solr\includes\solr_connection.inc).

Does the filter have an issue with large files or is there a problem with my config ?

Also, what does

> position increments (and gaps) must be >= 0 (got 65536) for field
>   'tm_attachments_field_fichier'

in the error message mean ?  If it returned 65536, it is greater that 0 ...

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

well, 65536 is negative number assuming that you are using 16 bit number(as max positive number is 65535 in 16 bit integer). More precisely, 65536 is equal to -1.